# Contract only modifier

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity

I am writing a smart contract which will contain an escrow service. The escrow is to be a smart contract and eventually I want to use it to transfer meta tokens from the escrows address to another user. The issue I have is that I want to be able to transfer from the escrow but have a modifier which allows only the escrow contract itself to call. I have tried to make a modifier which only allows "this" (referring to the contract address) to make the call but that doesn't work.

If a contract internally calls another function how can I have it that only the contract itself can call the function and have the transfer happen. Msg.sender doesn't seem to accommodate for this.

My Code:

```
  modifier contractOnly(){
    address contractAddress = this;
    if(msg.sender != contractAddress) throw; _
}
```

and the transfer function (which needs the modifier to prevent anyone from calling the function and taking all the tokens from the escrow)

```
  function transfer(address from, address to, uint amount)
    contractOnly returns (uint) {
    balances[from] -= amount;
    balances[to] += amount;
    return balances[from];
}
```

Comment: Why cant you specify the function as internal? Is anyone calling that function or only a function in the same contract ?

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to write your function like this using the `internal` modifier which is built into solidity.

```
function transfer(address from, address to, uint amount) internal returns (uint) {
    balances[from] -= amount;
    balances[to] += amount;
    return balances[from];
}
```

This will mean that the `transfer` function will only be callable from within the function bodies of the other functions in this contract. Conversely the `transfer` function will not be callable from from any other contract.

The modifier you provided will work *if* the the contract actually calls itself (rather than just internally invoking the function).

```
contract MyInterface {
    modifier contractOnly(){
        address contractAddress = this;
        if(msg.sender != contractAddress) throw; _
    }
    function transfer(address from, address to, uint amount) contractOnly returns (uint);
}

contract TheContract is MyInterface {
    function transfer(address from, address to, uint amount) contractOnly returns (uint) {
        ...
    }

    function thisWillWork(address from, address to, uint amount) {
        MyInterface(address(this)).transfer(from, to, amount);
    }

    function thisWillFail(address from, address to, uint amount) {
        transfer(from, to, amount);
    }
}
```

In this example, the `thisWillWork` function calls the `transfer` function as an internal transaction, meaning a transaction between two contracts.  As it turns out, it is merely transacting with itself, but it is doing so as an external call.  In this case the `msg.sender` value becomes `address(this)` because the call is happening in a transaction initiated by the contract itself.

The `thisWillFail` function uses an internal call style meaning that it doesn't produce an internal transaction, but instead just calls the `transfer` function's code within the current running transaction using a `JUMPDEST`.  In this case, the `msg.sender` value is preserved as the original caller because the call is not happening in a new transaction, but in the context of the current transaction.