# What is the best way to test calling a contract's function from another contract?

Tags: solidity, truffle, contract-debugging, truffle-console

I'm playing around w/ [Gnosis' MultiSigWallet](https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/MultiSigWallet.sol) and noticed in their `replaceOwner` function it has a modifier that requires `msg.sender` to be the MultiSigWallet contract itself:

```
modifier onlyWallet() {
    require(msg.sender == address(this));
    _;
}
```

In Truffle console, how would I go about testing this and calling the `replaceOwner` function from the MultiSigWallet's address? I.e., if I try something like this:

```
wallet.replaceOwner('owner_address','newOwner_address', {from: 'multisigwallet_address'})
```

I'll get an `Error: sender account not recognized`

Is there a way within Truffle's console to make calls from contract addresses or is it only possible to make calls from the user addresses?

This [post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7814/contract-only-modifier?rq=1) is related and I understand how this works, but I'm more curious to see if we can do this easily w/in Truffle for expedient testing purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go (got plenty more coverage for this contract if you're interested):

```
contract("MultiSigWallet", function(accounts) {
    let hMultiSigWallet;

    let utils = require("./utils");

    let NUM_OF_OWNERS    = 6;
    let NUM_OF_REQ_CONFS = 5;

    let owners   = accounts.slice(1, 1 + NUM_OF_OWNERS);
    let newOwner = accounts[1 + NUM_OF_OWNERS];

    beforeEach(async function() {
        hMultiSigWallet = await artifacts.require("MultiSigWallet").new(owners, NUM_OF_REQ_CONFS);
    });

    describe("functional assertion:", function() {
        it("function replaceOwner should abort with an error if called with a non-existing current owner", async function() {
            await execute(hMultiSigWallet.contract.replaceOwner, [newOwner, newOwner], "ExecutionFailure");
        });
        it("function replaceOwner should abort with an error if called with an already-existing new owner", async function() {
            await execute(hMultiSigWallet.contract.replaceOwner, [owners[0], owners[0]], "ExecutionFailure");
        });
        it("function replaceOwner should complete successfully if called with legal input arguments", async function() {
            await execute(hMultiSigWallet.contract.replaceOwner, [owners[0], newOwner], "Execution");
        });
    });

    async function execute(func, args, state) {
        let submitReceipt = await hMultiSigWallet.submitTransaction(hMultiSigWallet.address, 0, func.getData(...args), {from: owners[0]});
        let transactionId = utils.getParamFromTxEvent(submitReceipt, "transactionId", null, "Submission");
        for (let i = 1; i < NUM_OF_REQ_CONFS - 1; i++) {
            let confirmReceipt   = await hMultiSigWallet.confirmTransaction(transactionId, {from: owners[i]});
            let newTransactionId = utils.getParamFromTxEvent(confirmReceipt, "transactionId", null, "Confirmation");
            assert(newTransactionId.equals(transactionId), `expected = ${transactionId}, actual = ${newTransactionId}`);
        }
        let confirmReceipt   = await hMultiSigWallet.confirmTransaction(transactionId, {from: owners[NUM_OF_REQ_CONFS - 1]});
        let newTransactionId = utils.getParamFromTxEvent(confirmReceipt, "transactionId", null, state);
        assert(newTransactionId.equals(transactionId), `expected = ${transactionId}, actual = ${newTransactionId}`);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just make sure that you start Ganache with a sufficient number of accounts (at least `NUM_OF_OWNERS + 2`).

Comment: Thanks! So, it looks like the fastest way to test is w/ unit tests? There's no easy / quick way to do it w/in `truffle console`?

Comment: @dougiebuckets: I don't use `truffle console` so it's hard for me to answer this question, but you can get it running via `truffle test`.

Comment: @dougiebuckets The trick is that, as you pointed out, the contract itself has to call `replaceOwner`. The only way to get it to do that is the same way you make the contract do anything; call `submitTransaction` and then `confirmTransaction` a sufficient number of times from the various owner accounts. So there's no quick shortcut to this... it's the nature of the contract you're using.